# Alert looping… Why?

Tags: alert, simplecart

I am facing a very annoying problem. I use js SimpleCart to buy tickets for shows. There are places for adults and children. So I create two inputs to select the number of adults and number of children. When adding to cart, I check the value of each field is a number with "beforeAdd." If "yes" I check the second field. If "no" I displays a alert.
The first field responds very well. But the second loop indefinitely on the alert in the first field.
I do not understand it. Has anybody an idea?

Here is the code

```
    $('.item_add').click(function()
    {
        var id_des_produits = this.id;
        var selecteur = 'selec' + id_des_produits;
        var selectionne = ' option:selected';
        var valeur_select_photo_ie = $('#selec' + id_des_produits + selectionne).val();
        var nombre_adulte = $('#nbre_adulte' + id_des_produits).val();
        var nombre_enfant = $('#nbre_enfant' + id_des_produits).val();
        var nombre_participant = nombre_adulte + nombre_enfant;
        var date_d_arrivee = $('.calendrier_front' + id_des_produits).val();
        var categorie = $('#date' + id_des_produits).val();
        var nom_produit = $('.item_name').html();
        var prix_enfant = 10;
        var prix_adulte = 23;
        var thumb_produit = $('#thumb_produit_' + id_des_produits).attr('src');

        simpleCart.bind("beforeAdd", function(item)
        {
            if(chiffre_check.test(nombre_adulte))
            {
                if(nombre_adulte != '0')
                {
                    simpleCart.add(
                    {
                        name: nom_produit + '</br>Tarif adulte' ,
                        price: prix_adulte ,
                        size: date_d_arrivee ,
                        quantity: nombre_adulte ,
                        thumb: thumb_produit 
                    });
                }
            return true;
            }   
            else
            {
                alert('Précisez le nombre d\'adulte');
                return false;
            }
            if(chiffre_check.test(nombre_enfant))
            {
                if(nombre_enfant != '0')
                {
                    simpleCart.add(
                    {
                        name: nom_produit + '</br>Tarif enfant' ,
                        price: prix_enfant ,
                        size: date_d_arrivee ,
                        quantity: nombre_enfant ,
                        thumb: thumb_produit 
                    });
                }
            return true;
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Précisez le nombre d\'enfant');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adds are being done inside a function that is bound to the `beforeAdd` event.

This means that when the adds inside the function are performed, it will immediately trigger the same event handler again, resulting in the infinite cycle you're seeing.

What is happening is as follows:

1. An "add" is done to the cart.
2. This triggers the event handler to start.
3. The first test passes, number of adults is >0 so it adds the Adult Tariff.
4. This "add" triggers the event to start again, but it waits until the current code is finished.
5. The current code carries on, and the second test fails thus throwing the alert.
6. The alert is cleared, the current code finished, so the event triggered earlier is called.
7. You are now back at stage 2 above.

As you can see, although what you're seeing is the alert from the second test being repeated, it's actually the successful first test and the add that is done by it that is causing the loop. It is also causing the adult tariff to be added an infinite number of times, which probably isn't your intention!

To get around this sort of thing, you'll need an additional check at the start of the event trigger function, which tells it to exit if the item being added is of the type that is added by itself.

A possible solution might look something like this:

```
simpleCart.bind("beforeAdd", function(item)
    {
    if(item.name.match(/(Tarif adulte|Tarif enfant)$/))
        {
        return;  //exit the event handler if it's one of the tarif items, to prevent the event handler looping.
        }
    //.... rest of your existing code for the beforeAdd function continues here...
```

This solution is based on the name of the items; you may want to tweak the conditions in the `if()` to suit your exact case.

Hope that helps.